# Converting NSDATA

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm using Shuttle Magstripe reader and I'm converting the response `[notification object]` to NSData then converting it to NSString

```
NSData* data = [notification object];
NSString* response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But when i try to `NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", response);`

The  output is just an inverted `?` Any Ideas on how to properly process Swipe response for Shuttle MagStripe reader?

Comment: Where are the specs for the data it sends?  Nevermind, you have to buy the kit in order to look at that...there are probably not many people that can help you because we don't know what the data is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, pass the information as

```
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:<#yourNSDataObject> forKey:@"pass"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myevent" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

and on the receiver methord get the object like

```
- (void)receiveEvent:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSData pass = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"pass"];
}
```